# Improve precision when working with series

Tags: c++, precision

I was assigned a task to work on a variation of the Riemann Hypothesis. I created the following below which works fine, but I realize that with integer division I reach a point where I can no longer run test results (around 106 runs). I'm not sure if there may be anything else however which may be causing my program to stop running after around 106 iterations. Are there any ways to improve this code so that I can run more test results?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int omegaN(int n){
    int omega[100] = {};
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if ((n%i) == 0 ){
            omega[i] = i;
        }
        sum += (omega[i]);
    }
    cout << "\nSum of omega: " << sum << endl;
    return sum;
}

double Hn (int n){
    double sum = 0;
    double h_n;
    double whatBraunWants = 0;
    for (int i = 1.0; i <= n; i++){
        h_n = 1.0/i;
        sum += h_n;
    }
    cout << "Sum of Hn: " << sum << endl;
    whatBraunWants = sum + log(sum) * exp(sum);
    cout << "What Hn plus natural log stuff equals: " << whatBraunWants << endl;
    return whatBraunWants;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        cout << "\nUsing n = " << i;
        if (omegaN(i) <= Hn(i)){
            cout << "Good for when n = " << i << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "No good when n = " << i << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double` has 53 bits of mantissa. Probably your code generates 1 bit of precision each 2 loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was a bit tricky. In the line

```
int omega[100] = {};
```

inside `omegaN(int n)` you fix the size of the array `omega` to 100. However, you perform an out-of-bound access when `omegaN`'s input parameter `n >= 100`. You end up overwriting some memory you shouldn't (undefined behaviour), so all hell breaks lose.

Just allocate more on the stack, like `int omega[1024];`, or, better, use dynamic allocation

```
int* omega = new int[n]; // now we know for sure we have enough storage space
```

and don't forget to

```
delete[] omega;
```

before `return`-ing from `omegaN`.

Or, even better, use a smart pointer from `<memory>` (C++11/14) and replace

```
int omega[100];
```

with

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> omega(new int[n]{}); // or use std::make_unique in C++14
```

The `std::unique_ptr` destructor will take care of releasing the memory.

PS: you can also use a `std::shared_ptr`, however it is a bit more trickier to use with arrays, as unfortunately doesn't have a specialization for `T[]`, and you have to provide a custom deleter.

PPS: I'd also replace `i <= n` with `i < n` for loop conditions, as with the former it's easy to access past the last element of the array/pointer.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely forgot I had set my array to 100 when I was first making that function. That alone fixed everything!

Comment: @Valrok, yeah, was a bit tricky, I find out since your program spitted out a segfault, and you didn't use any memory allocation/recursion, so out of bounds was the only culprit.